# Get required form elements value is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make my form only show the "Read Terms" button after all of the required elements are filled. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35396980/get-required-form-elements-via-dom-in-javascript) to get the required elements but now when I try to get the value of the elements they return undefined in the Chrome developer tools.

```
// Show Terms Button only if all required elements are filled.
let termsButton = document.getElementById("termsButton");
let allRequired = document.getElementById("contactForm").querySelectorAll("[required]");
const checkForRequiredDone = () =>{
    if (allRequired.value != undefined && allRequired.value != "" && allRequired.value != null){
        termsButton.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        termsButton.style.display = "none;"
    }
}
```

Since I'm testing for not undefined, even if all of the required elements are filled the button is still showing.

Also this is on an `onchange` attribute on the form element.

And also I do have jQuery but I thought this would be easier in JS...

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a **list**. The list doesn't have a `value` property. The elements in it do (assuming their form fields).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder After looking at the similar question and answer, I'm still not sure how I would go about getting the values of each and checking if they aren't equal to undefined or blank or null. I've tried multiple methods using for...

Comment: A loop is indeed how you'd do it. Or apply `Array#some` or `Array#every` to the NodeList: `if (Array.prototype.some.call(allRequired, element => !element.value)) { /* At least one is blank */ } else { /* All are non-blank */ }` Also note that the `value` of an element will never be `undefined` or `null`, it's a string.

Comment: Thank you! This worked well.